# Videos not showing in webview (Android)

Tags: android

I am implementing a web application for Android. In this application, I open a HTML page on webview. This HTML page contains videos, images and text. When I call this page, all stuff are showing except for videos. What can I do? Please help me.

I am using this code for this problem:

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
web. getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
web. getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically (false);
web. getSettings().setPluginsEnabled (true);
web. getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows (false);
web. getSettings().setSupportZoom (false);
web. setVerticalScrollBarEnabled (false);
web. setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled (false);
web. loadUrl ("http://www.abc.com/xyz.html");            
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: I did an application to run HTML5 on a WebView too, and the videos doesn't work also.

Comment: Does your URL work in the native browser?

Answer (score 0):

get a WebViewClient to check what url is on a hyperlink, if it is a video, you can redirect it to an embedded player.